# Shortening sentence by removing nouns repeating in clauses

Tags: nouns, syntactic-analysis, clauses

In the following sentence, a noun is repeated in each clause. The noun I refer to is *assignment*.

> He is aware of the assignment, accepts the assignment and endeavours
>   to fulfil the assignment.

Is it correct for me to write the sentence in a manner that shortens the sentence by writing the noun once per sentence rather than once per clause?

> He is aware of, accepts and endeavours to fulfil the assignment.

Comment: Why complicate? The most important word here is "assignment", don't move it to the end. We have a pronoun specially for such a situation. "He is aware of the assignment, accepts **it**, and endeavours to fulfill **it**." Unless you are drafting a legal document, in which case, a proper legal "conveyancing" will be needed.

Comment: @Kris The placement of the noun in the first clause and use of pronoun in subsequent clauses reads well. Your recommendation and explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. However, you will lose an emphasis on "the assignment" and to the reader, after having said "he is aware of the assignment" and then repeated assignment assignment assignment, we really get the picture that he sure is aware of that assignment.

Comment: Thank you explaining that both are acceptable and that the only deciding factor is the intended emphasis of the noun.

Comment: See also: my comment at OP.