# Using an article plus an adjective without a noun and another article plus a singular noun

Tags: grammar, nouns, articles, indefinite-articles

Please consider the following, guys.
*I met **a good** and **a bad mother** on the way here*
What I am trying to say: There were two mothers, one bad and one good.
Is it okay to use that construction? Or need I remove the articles and use *mothers* instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plural or singular noun when it refers to two things in a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221331/plural-or-singular-noun-when-it-refers-to-two-things-in-a-list) In your example, repeating the article strongly implies there are ***two different mothers***, whereas omitting the second one implies a ***single*** mother (who is both good ***and*** bad). Plural ***mothers*** (with ***no*** articles, obviously) could refer to ***any number*** of mothers - some good, some bad.

Comment: (a) 'I met a good mother and a bad mother ....' Totally correct, though a little ponderous in many contexts. // (b) 'I met a good and a bad mother ....' Totally correct; the usual choice.   // (c) 'I met a good and bad mother ....' Sounds odd, and means you met one mother who displayed both good and bad traits.  // (d) 'I met good and bad mothers ....'  At least 2 in each category.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth what if I said *I met good and bad mothers, one good and one bad*. Would it make any sense?

Comment: No, that's not idiomatic. It _might_ just be used by an educated native speaker for effect, probably comedic, but it is a marked usage. 'Yesterday I met two mothers – one good and one bad' is more natural.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @FadliSheikh *I met good and bad mothers, one good and one bad* sounds quite reasonable if used in the context of a riddle (*How many mothers did I meet*?) but the fact that there are only two makes it slightly unusual. On the other hand, purely in terms of how we use language, this would be fine: *I met good and bad mothers, some tall, some short, five good, and one bad.* The reason why that sounds more natural is because there are many mothers, not just two. If there are only two, we would normally phrase it this way: *I met **two** mothers, one good and one bad.*

Comment: @FadliSheikh But, also, it would be somewhat redundant to mention good and bad mothers twice, Even better, in case of many mothers, would be one of the following: (1) *I met good and bad mothers, some tall and some short.* (2) *I met many mothers, some tall, some short, five good, and one bad.* In short, there are multiple issues with the original sentence in the comment describing only two mothers. However, purely syntactically, it's fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortening sentence by removing nouns repeating in clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/454528/shortening-sentence-by-removing-nouns-repeating-in-clauses) Your actual question is not just about nouns and adjectives, but the omission of a noun in any repeated (and parallel) construction.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for the great answers. Now, how do I pick out one as the best answer?